# Why do properties of colloidal solution depend only on dispersion medium's physical state?

Tags: mixtures, colloids

According to a past year JEE question, properties of colloidal solution depends only on dispersion medium's physical state and not on nature of dispersed phase or dispersion medium, or temperature of system. I cannot find any further information on this subject. I would like some clearer guidance on this. Would someone please help?

Comment: Which properties? I guess that's only about things like melting/boiling point.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that properties of colloidal dispersion only depends on the medium is completely incorrect. The vague part of the question is "properties" in the question, because the examiner is not clear about what type of properties he/she is talking about. It is not uncommon to find open ended questions in public exams. The properties of colloidal solutions heavily depend on the temperature (since their viscosity is temperature dependent as well as flow rate dependent). Similarly, the size of colloidal particle controls the optical properties of the dispersion. Similarly the surface charge on the particles determines the sign/magnitude of the zeta potential. If you want to read further, read DLVO theory (named after four persons) on the stability of the colloids from Wikipedia. One should not worry about an incorrect question. If it were a true-false question, one can simply mark it false.